# Cordova Android ICordovaCookieManager use from plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I'm trying, from a Cordova plugin, to set a cookie to the webview.
I've checked the cordova-android source and it appears that there is a CookieManager interface.
When I'm trying to use it, the cookie isn't set when I inspect the webview.

```
 @Override
 public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);  

    ICordovaCookieManager cookieManager = webView.getCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    cookieManager.setCookie("https://com.myapp", "test=test");
 }
```

Note that I'm using the `https://com.myapp` as host as it is set in the `hostname` preference. I've also tried `http://localhost` and `https://localhost`..

How do I use `ICordovaCookieManager` to set a cookie ?

Comment: I think you are doing this in the wrong way, see this! https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/main/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/cordova/CapacitorCordovaCookieManager.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question since I've found the solution
The code actually works! The issue is between scheme / hostname and inspecting.

The scheme actually does not set webView location, it always falls back onto `https://`, even if you set it to `app://`.

Then when I inspect the webview, it is loaded by default with `file://` because I had `AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled` set to `true`, so I do need to reload the webview and use the proper url `https://com.myapp`, and finally I see my cookies, or remove `AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled`.

Comment: Eric, please contact me, based on your activity, I'd like to hire you for cordova help pretty please!  This is the only way I know how to reach out from this platform.